# java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: multithreading, scala, executorservice, executor

I have an integrated executor service to execute the tasks concurrently and when used without `Future`, everything is working fine. In order to check tasks completion and no failure from the executor threads, I have added an `Future` and trying to check failure state.

Sample Code:

```scala
val pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_COUNT)
implicit val context = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(pool)

var index = 0
while (index < employeeJobDataList.size()) {
    val startIndex = index
    var endIndex = index + BATCH_THRESHOLD

    if (startIndex + BATCH_THRESHOLD >= employeeJobDataList.size()) {
        endIndex = employeeJobDataList.size()
    }

    val future = Future({
        upsertsFailedBatches.addAll(batchSaveInDDB(employeeJobDataList.subList(startIndex, endIndex), failedList))
    })
    future.onFailure { case e : Throwable => errorFromExecutorService . append (e.toString) }
    index = index + BATCH_THRESHOLD
}

context.shutdown()
while (!context.isTerminated()) {
    Thread.sleep(THREAD_SLEEP_TIME_MILLI)
}
```

Error details:

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable@74a938eb rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@5e5fcd94[Shutting down, pool size = 10, active threads = 10, queued tasks = 87323, completed tasks = 213]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2063)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:830)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1379)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$$anon$1.execute(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:136)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:252)
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:157)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:23)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: You are invoking shutdown on the context before the Future tasks have finished (you're doing it immediately). Also, you don't explain why you are creating your own thread pool and executor service. I can't really see any reason why you would need to roll your own.